# C program compilation with VC++ [2005]

Tags: c, visual-c++

I can see that my VC++ 2005 express edition compiles following code perfectly

```
/*Following Code compiles fine*/
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i;
    int;
    5;

    printf("\n\r Whats up??");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

However I have observed that it gives compilation error for same code with slightly different order.

```
/*Following code gives error*/

#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int;
    5;

    int i;
    printf("\n\r Whats up??");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Position of "int i" is different in both the cases. 
I get error as "Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   on line 6.

Why is this happening?

Thanks,

Comment: What error do you receive? Declaring variables (as "int i;") without initialising should at least give you a warning.

Comment: You really should upgrade your compiler VS2005 for C/C++ is an abomination.

Comment: Visual C lags some 15 years behind the C language. C99 is still not fully supported as of VS2013. VS2005 is from the previous geological epoch. Use it at your own peril. By the way your program is non-standard because (1) you cannot omit function return types so `main()` is illegal and (2) each declaration must declare something and `int;` declares nothing.

Comment: C89 requires variable declarations *before* statements in a function body.  The nonsensical `5;` is a statement, so the `i` variable declaration after it is not recognized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because it seems the compiler has a bug. Neither the first program nor the second program shall be compiled.

I can guess that the second program is not compiled because declarations in old C must be placed in the beginning of a code block.

I have no at hand the old C Standard but according to the current C Standard (6.7 Declarations)

> 2 A declaration other than a static_assert declaration **shall declare
>   at least a declarator** (other than the parameters of a function or
>   the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an
>   enumeration.

It seems that the old C allowed empty declarations. At least in the Rationale for International Standard— Programming Languages— C Revision 2 20 October 1999 there is written:

> 6.7 Declarations 25
>   **The C89 Committee decided that empty declarations are invalid**, except for a special case with tags (see §6.7.2.3) and the case of
>   enumerations such as enum {zero,one}; (see §6.7.2.2). While many
>   seemingly silly constructs are tolerated in other parts of the
>   language in the interest of facilitating the machine generation of C,
>   empty declarations were considered sufficiently easy to 30 avoid.

Take into account that some compiler implementations call such bugs as their own language extensions.:)

Comment: Both compile fine in GCC, giving the warning "warning: useless type name in empty declaration"

Comment: @slugonamission When will be that day when "something will appear here"?:)

Comment: GCC changes this warning into error with `-ansi -pedantic-errors`. Old (C90) Standard requires that: `"A declaration shall declare at least a declarator, a tag, or the members of an enumeration."` (6.5 Declarations).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - eh, maybe one day :P

Comment: The code has nothing to do with "empty declarations". "Empty declarations" is a completely different issue. In C an empty declaration is created when a standalone `;` is used at file scope. Why `int;` compiles in this case is a completely unrelated matter. `int;` is not an empty declaration. It is impossible to say whether it is a declaration at all, since the language does not support it. The compiler apparently sees it as a declaration though.

Comment: @AndreyT Your remark does not agree with the quote of the C Rationale where enumerations are mentioned.